# Can't generate java code from WSDL

Tags: web-services, jboss, intellij-idea, jbossws

I want to generate java code from wsdl for my `jbossws` client. I am using Intelij Idea 12
Here is the procedure I followed.

Right click on the package > webservices > generate java code from wsdl

but it only creates a file same as `wsdl` not java code classes. 
What is the wrong thing I did?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you define Axis runtime environment in your IDE. In Axis package, there is file called (wsdl2java.bat) for window or (wsdl2java.sh) for linux environment which could help to generate java source from wsdl, Check out those file exists or not. Please refer below site.

http://www.gerd-riesselmann.net/scala/creating-java-classes-wsdl-file-using-apache-axis-2

Good luck!